# Angular.js for polling data from server and refresh at intervals

Tags: angularjs

I tried to set up a simple app to show the latest message of each member.

At first, it loads the members array.Then I call a function refreshMsg to loop through the array.

Within the loop, I set an timer on it.

However it did not work at all.Could someone five me an hint?

Many thanks.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2D76t/)

```
  //show the message for each member and set an timer to refesh
   function refreshMsg(){
    //loop through members array and set a timer
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.members.length;i++){           
            var cur_member=$scope.members[i];
            var name = cur_member.name;
            var url_getMsg = "api/getMsg/".name;
            var timer = $timeout( function refresh(){
                    $http.get(url_getMsg).success(function(data){                           
                            cur_member.msg=data;                                
                        }
                    )
                    timer = $timeout(refresh, 3000);
                }, 3000);

    }   
}
})
```

Comment: Looks like the natural way would be to use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons it is not working correctly is that due to async nature of the call the cur_member would not match the response message as the loop would have moved ahead. The way to do this would be to create another method specifically for setting the $timeout which would create a closure. Better still use $interval

```
function refreshMsg(){
    //loop through members array and set a timer
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.members.length;i++){           
            var cur_member=$scope.members[i];
            var name = cur_member.name;
            setupRefresh(curr_member);

    }   
    function setupRefresh(member) {
            var url_getMsg = "api/getMsg/"+member.name;
            var timer = $interval( function(){
                    $http.get(url_getMsg).success(function(data){                           
                            member.msg=data;                                
                        }
                    );
                }, 3000);
    }
```

Also remember to dispose all the `interval` when scope is destroyed.